# Using jq select elements with keys containing some string, key preserved in results

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I have a JSON content as embedded in this link [jq-play](https://jqplay.org/s/npoAQkfK9V). The JSON content is large and couldn't be accommodated here.

Currently, I manage to get the values by

```
[.[keys[] | select(contains("VMIMAGE"))]]
```

but the key names, i.e. `CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-F1-MICRO` aren't present in the result. How do I get it?

Comment: How do you want the result? The content related to `CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-F1-MICRO` is present in the results. You want the key names to be printed like `CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-F1-MICRO` and `CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-G1-SMALL` or body of those key names?

Comment: I'd like to have both if possible, otherwise, how do I know which is corresponding to which?

Comment: In future, please adhere to the [mcve] guidelines.  Apart from clarifying the question, that will also help to make it more self-contained and useful to others.

Comment: Where is the JSON? The link goes to an empty jq-play.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like you want to take a "slice" of the object by selecting just those keys containing a certain string.  Using your query as a model, this can most easily be accomplished using a query of the form `with_entries( select(...) )`, e.g.:

```
.gcp_price_list
| with_entries( select(.key|contains("VMIMAGE")))
```

Comment: just about the same time I figured it out

Comment: How to print the value of the matching key please?

Comment: @GillesQuénot

`jq '.gcp_price_list | to_entries[] | select(.key | contains("VMIMAGE")) | .key'`

stolen [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739707/59604)